# Array To Check Column For Matched Value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match

I would like to seek your help for my issue:

I would like to check if the row value in Column Q of Workbook A is "WIN".

If yes, then return 1 in the corresponding row in Column BL of Workbook A.

If no, then return 0 in the corresponding row in Column BL of Workbook A.

I have applied a VBA-based array to carry out the check but unfortunately, I am only getting 1, not 0...

My (non-working) code is below:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim j, LastRowOutcomeCleaned As Long
Dim arrQ, arrBL As Variant
Dim answer, found As Range
  
Set ws = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Sheets(2)
LastRow = ws.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

arrQ = ws.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Value 
arrBL = ws.Range("BL2:BL" & LastRow).Value 

ReDim arrBL(1 To UBound(arrQ), 1 To 1) 

For j = 1 To UBound(arrQ)
    answer = "WIN"
    
    Set found = ws.Columns("Q:Q").Find(what:=answer)
    
    If found Is Nothing Then
        arrBL(j, 1) = "0"  
    Else
        arrBL(j, 1) = "1" 
    End If
Next j

ws.Range("BL1").Resize(UBound(arrBL), 1).Value = arrBL
```

Many thanks!

Comment: you are searching the whole column each time inside the loop.  Instead of `Set found = ws.Columns("Q:Q").Find(what:=answer)` use `IF arrQ(j,1)=answer then`

Comment: and probably replace `"0"` with `0` and `"1"` with `1` you don't want numbers as strings.

Comment: Also note that `Dim j, LastRowOutcomeCleaned As Long` declares `j As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim j As Long, LastRowOutcomeCleaned As Long` otherwise it is `Variant` by default. • Same for your other variables.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! Noted on using arrQ(j,1)=answer to reduce processing time. The Power BI Report seems to recognize the 0 or 1, regardless of data type so I think it should be ok. Noted on declaring every variable, I was previously unaware of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find will search the entire column each time in the loop so if the value exist anywhere in the column the whole output array will return 1.  If you want a row by row test then test each row:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim j As Long, LastRowOutcomeCleaned As Long
Dim arrQ as Variant, arrBL As Variant
Dim answer as string

'Note: this is dangerous as the order of sheets may change
'      Consider using the codename instead.  
Set ws = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Sheets(2) 
LastRow = ws.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

arrQ = ws.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Value 
'Next line not needed as you redim it right after.
'arrBL = ws.Range("BL2:BL" & LastRow).Value 

ReDim arrBL(1 To UBound(arrQ), 1 To 1) 

For j = 1 To UBound(arrQ)
    answer = "WIN"
    
    If arrQ(j,1)=answer Then
        arrBL(j, 1) = 1  
    Else
        arrBL(j, 1) = 0 
    End If
Next j

ws.Range("BL1").Resize(UBound(arrBL), 1).Value = arrBL
```

Comment: Thank you! It's now working! So that was why the entire column was made up of "1"s...